# How do I disable negative scaling?

Tags: interface, transforms

By default blender allows you to scale past 0 - how do I prevent this?

i.e. it's common in other 3D modelling software to resize a set of vertices against an axis to align them - however this isn't possible when negative scaling is enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible, use the keyboard input instead.

After pressing <kbd>S</kbd> for scaling use the keyboard to enter <kbd>0</kbd> (zero) to perfectly align geometry and optionaly choose an axis of alignment by pressing either <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: Well that's arguably quicker, and the goal with that workflow is always to hit exactly 0, so I won't complain; thank you :) Would definitely be nice to have that option though, was the first tickbox I located when picking up Modo.

Comment: This can probably be achieved relatively easily with some sort of python script or a simple addon, but that is beyond my skills

Comment: This is the best way to do it, but if you need to scale to a different limit than 0, you can press Shift while scaling, this will make scaling smooth enough to get an accurate result, you can use Shift with rotation an translation too.

Comment: This is not an answer.  Scaling with the mouse is always useful IN-ADDITION to the mentioned method

Answer (score -3):

Select the mesh in OBJECT mode - Object Tab - Apply *cntrl A* - Rotation & Scale.

The error is coming up because when you're unwrapping it, it doesn't like the rotation and scale.

IDK how I just figured that out myself considering I was looking up the same issue and remembered scale can mean the rotation/scale/orgin of a mesh as well.

Comment: Did you post this on the wrong question?